# Why does the JSR operation not jump?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am building a computer based on the 65C02S, and when stepping through the code, I see strange things happening.

This is my code:

```
SEI
CLD
LDX #$ff
TXS

JSR someRoutine
...
```

This translates to this behaviour (when stepping though and monitoring with an Arduino):

```
READ  address:   80 0d   1000.0000 0000.1101   data:   78   0111.1000 SEI
READ  address:   80 0e   1000.0000 0000.1110   data:   d8   1101.1000 CLD
READ  address:   80 0e   1000.0000 0000.1110   data:   d8   1101.1000 d8 
READ  address:   80 0f   1000.0000 0000.1111   data:   a2   1010.0010 LDX
READ  address:   80 0f   1000.0000 0000.1111   data:   a2   1010.0010 a2 
READ  address:   80 10   1000.0000 0001.0000   data:   ff   1111.1111 ff 
READ  address:   80 11   1000.0000 0001.0001   data:   9a   1001.1010 TXS
READ  address:   80 12   1000.0000 0001.0010   data:   20   0010.0000 JSR
READ  address:   80 12   1000.0000 0001.0010   data:   20   0010.0000 JSR
READ  address:   80 13   1000.0000 0001.0011   data:   28   0010.1000 28 
READ  address:   01 ff   0000.0001 1111.1111   data:   80   1000.0000 ---
WRITE address:   01 ff   0000.0001 1111.1111   data:   80   1000.0000 ---
WRITE address:   01 fe   0000.0001 1111.1110   data:   ff   1111.1111 ---    ; Why write FF?
READ  address:   80 14   1000.0000 0001.0100   data:   80   1000.0000 80 
READ  address:   ff ff   1111.1111 1111.1111   data:   ff   1111.1111 ---
READ  address:   80 14   1000.0000 0001.0100   data:   80   1000.0000 80     ; Why not jump?
READ  address:   80 15   1000.0000 0001.0101   data:   a9   1010.1001 LDA
```

As you can see, the WRITEs are already weird (why write `80 ff`, when the PC is at `80 12` at that point?), but also, the `JSR` doesn't seem to jump at all, it just continues at `80 14`.

I first thought it might be some noise somewhere, but the behaviour is always the same. I also tried adding the reset code (`SEI`, etc), but that just gives slightly different, incorrect, results. I am trying to figure out if my code is wrong, or that I should look at other parts somewhere (noise, design ...)

For clarity, this is the binary code that I am running:

```
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f  72 6c 64 21 00 78 d8 a2  |Hello World!.x..|
00000010  ff 9a 20 28 80 a9 00 85  10 a9 80 85 11 20 5d 80  |.. (......... ].|
00000020  ea 4c 20 80 a2 ff 9a 60  a9 00 8d f8 7f 8d f9 7f  |.L ....`........|
00000030  a9 30 20 45 80 a9 01 20  45 80 a9 0f 20 45 80 60  |.0 E... E... E.`|
00000040  3a 8d f9 7f 60 8d f8 7f  a9 01 8d f9 7f 20 40 80  |:...`........ @.|
00000050  60 8d f8 7f a9 05 8d f9  7f 20 40 80 60 a0 00 b1  |`........ @.`...|
00000060  10 f0 07 20 51 80 c8 4c  5f 80 60                 |... Q..L_.`|
```

**Update** I created a very simple program that loops forever, with a simple `JMP` and that runs fine. Which make me think noise is not a problem here.

**Update** This is how I attach the Arduino (pin 2 is connected to PHI2 (pin 37) of the CPU):

```
#define CLOCK 2

pinMode(CLOCK, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(CLOCK), onClock, FALLING);
```

**Update** I attached an oscilloscope to the databus and see that at some point the level is 1.5V instead of 0 or 5, so I think the design is failing somewhere...

**Update** this is my design:

[image]

Comment: Somewhere in between that loops-forever and your Hello World! is a simplest program that exhibits this strange behaviour. Can you try to find at least one, please?

Comment: Have you tried with another CPU? Even a new CPU can be broken, and sometimes in strange ways.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I see. Mind to tell at what points your 'trace' is taken? Using an Arduino sounds suspect at first. How is it connected? what does it exactly do, does it drive some liens? Maybe even just for a short period? Likewise, how does it continue?

Comment: Are you monitoring the SYNC signal with the Arduino?  That may give clues as to whether the 6502 is actually executing the instructions you think it is.  Also, be sure that you're sampling the address and data lines at the correct points in the clock cycle: addresses are valid at the rising edge of Phi2, but data is valid at the falling edge.  Finally, beware of counterfeit CPUs; while most genuine 65C02s can be run very slowly, many on eBay are actually older NMOS CPUs that have a minimum clock speed for correct operation.

Comment: Easy way to tell if it's CMOS or NMOS - measure current draw. CMOS only draws a few mA per MHz, while NMOS draws ~100mA at any frequency.

Comment: @Chromatix I have the clock signal connected to a clock input on the Arduin (pin 2), and read the info on the `RISING` edge (`attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(CLOCK), onClock, RISING);`. Also, I bought the 6502 from Mouser, so I reckon they are the 'right' ones.

Comment: @UncleBod I have swapped out the CPU and I see the same behaviour.

Comment: I think we also need to know the effective clock frequency.

Comment: @OmarL I am manually stepping through.

Comment: Thanks for all your remarks, made me look into the Arduino a little more critical. I set the pins to `INPUT_PULLUP`. Changing this to `INPUT` seems to have effect.

Comment: I suspect the data is taken form the setups databuss. To be able to answer , I think it is needed to know what is connected to the data bus, and probably the whole schematics of the computer you built, including the Arduino connections. The actual schematics, checked against reality, not how it was planned to be connected.

Comment: @UncleBod I can see the database is hovering around 1,5V when a WRITE is occurring. And yes, there is a 74273 connected to the databus. That 74273 should only enabled when a certain address is to be written, to create an output port.

Comment: Do you have any RAM configured for the CPU where the stack is supposed to be?

Comment: @UncleBod Yes, the first 32kB of memory is RAM, the upper 32kB is ROM.

Comment: If this is still an issue, please post the schematics. If it is not an issue, please edit the question or post an answer about what was wrong.

Comment: @UncleBod Added schematics

Comment: Can the CPU really access the stack ram at the address range $0100 – $01FF ( 256 – 511 )? It seems to me that you force bits 3 to 7 to be high to access the RAM...

Comment: @UncleBod, where do you get that? I am currently working with a scope, and I see my databus being screwed by the 74273.

Comment: What is the function of the two 74HC688 to the left? If you split the memorymap in 32kB RAM and 32 kB ROM, you only need A15 for chip select (inverted for one of the chips)

Comment: @UncleBod The idea is to take make 8 I/O addresses 7ff8 - 7fff, by hardwiring  A14-A3 and then use A0-A2 to select a 74x137. When this "I/O select bit is high, I disable both ROM and RAM. (That's what all the boolean logic does). The previous version used the A15 select for the ROM and that worked fine. I am adding outputs now, so I can program a display.

Comment: So, it worked before you added the decoding, and suddenly stopped working when you added it?

Comment: It did work before, but somehow I guess I screwed something up. And as said, I can see the data bus having a strange 1.5V level when this happens, while other times it is a nice 0 or 5. I also suspect noise. My main concern was if it is okay to wire those registers to the data bus.

Comment: Strange levels on the data bus is, if I remember correctly, either that nothing drives it (all drivers are in high impedance mode) or that two chips tries to drive it at the same time. Does the 6502 have any situations where it drives the data bus outside where it writes to RAM/IO ports? Is the RAM or ROM active at the same time? Did you make a mistake in the wiring when you expanded the project?

Comment: That schematic is way too complicated to debug like this. I would recommend stripping it down to the simplest version you can even if that means building it up on a breadboard. You can disconnect everything but the 6502 and Arduino and pull up (not drive!) the data bus to $EA, which is NOP, then see if the processor will step through all the addresses while single stepping. If that works, add on the next chunk and test.

Comment: @JoeyShepard that's what I did. This is already version 3 or so, and I built it on a breadboard. I even got the I/O to work at some point, but this seems to be an intermittent hardware bug. Or maybe even a wiring mistake. Well, after all the remarks I wanted to check if it is OK to attach a 74x273 to the databus. The original question doesn't make much sense anymore. It was just a symptom of something else. But, me being quite new to this stuff, I didn't know where to look. I want to thank everybody that helped me along this track, even though there is no clear cut answer to this question.

Comment: @UncleBod I tried some more debugging, and it is like the 6502 cannot drive the databus when writing. Each time there is a WRITE, and I disconnect the databus, I can see the levels floating as if not connected.

Comment: Without access to the physical circuit I can't help any more. I am sure one or more connections differs between the schematics and the physical circuit. This is not a question about retro computing. It is an electronics question.

Answer (score 1):

The 6502 cannot be single stepped, and neither can the 65C02, as they use DRAM cells for their internal registers.

If you want single-stepping, you have to buy a 65C02**S**.

Comment: I have this one: https://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/955-W65C02S6TPG-14

Comment: So it's a 65C02**S** from a reputable source. Single-stepping should not be a problem.